# Need help to transform SQL query into Solr query

Tags: join, solr

Please help me to transform following SQL query into Solr query.

```
SELECT PolicyNumber,EndorsementNumber
FROM Policy_Core a
WHERE AgencyCode = '500'
 AND PolicyNumber = 5201070001753
 AND EndorsementNumber = (SELECT MAX (EndorsementNumber)
                            FROM Policy_Core b
                           WHERE a.PolicyNumber = b.PolicyNumber).
```

I have one core in Solr server having following structure.

```
id (Unique ID) PolicyNumber(Number),  EndorsementNumber(Number), AgencyCode(Number)
5201070001753-1 5201070001753       ,1                   ,500
5201070001753-2 5201070001753       ,2                   ,500
5201070001753-3 5201070001753       ,3                   ,500
5201070001753-4 5201070001753       ,4                   ,100
5201070001753-5 5201070001753       ,5                   ,100
```

I have prepared following Solr query.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/db/select?q=PolicyNumber:5201070001753 AND AgencyCode:500 &fq={!collapse field=PolicyNumber max=EndorsementNumber}
```

This returns wrong result( As it is doing result Grouping). According to defined records into core, I am expecting Null/No results, But I getting one record with EndorsementNumber no 3.
Solr executes following query.I need help to create solr query to JOin POlicy core with itself to get max EndorsementNumber for PolicyNumber

```
SELECT PolicyNumber,EndorsementNumber
FROM Policy_Core a
WHERE AgencyCode = '500'
AND PolicyNumber = 5201070001753
GROUP BY PolicyNumber,EndorsementNumber HAVING EndorsementNumber = MAX(EndorsementNumber)
```

Comment: Have you looked at this link? https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Join   Check the section "Compared To SQL"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `EndorsementNumber` is a numeric field - such as [TrieIntField](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Field+Types+Included+with+Solr) - I think you can get the answer you want using the ["sort"](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#sort) and ["rows"](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#rows) query parameters. The following query should work:

`http://localhost:8983/solr/db/select?q=PolicyNumber:5201070001753 AND AgencyCode:500 &sort=EndorsementNumber desc&rows=1`

This would give you

```
id (Unique ID) PolicyNumber(Number),  EndorsementNumber(Number), AgencyCode(Number)
5201070001753-5 5201070001753       ,5                   ,100
```